# Creating stratified histogram using an R function

Tags: r, function, histogram

I am trying to create this stratified histogram on R, however I am not getting the right plot. I would like to use the rect function as well if possible.

[image: 1]

How would I write an R function to create this stratified histogram using the iris dataset in R?

This is the code so far:

```
strathist = function(x, y, ylab = "Frequency", xlab = "", main = ""){
  
  cols = hcl(h=seq(0, 360, by = 120))
  
  h = hist(x, breaks = 24, plot = FALSE)
  
  tb = table(y, cut(x, h$breaks))
  
  
  plot.new()
  
  barplot(tb, ylim = c(0, max(h$count)), col = cols,
          ylab = ylab, xlab = xlab, main = main, axisnames = FALSE) 
  
  box()
  axis(1, 0:(length(h$breaks)-1), h$breaks)
  axis(2)
  

  
  legend("topright", c(rownames(tb)), fill = cols)
}

with(iris, strathist(Sepal.Width, Species, xlab = "Sepal.Width", main = "Stratified Histogram"))
```

Comment: Hi Benjamen. What is your error? Is the image you posted the one you want to achieve, or is that the plot you have made? If so, what do you think is wrong with it? Could you please edit your question to give more details, including the code you have used that produces the error.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts. When you post here, you give SO the right to distribute the content under CC-by SA 4.0. Any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to delete your question there is a 'delete' link just below the question text.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different ways to do this, if you insist on using R base, you could use two barplots, one to add the colors and one to add the boxes:

```
strathist = function(x,
                     y,
                     ylab = "Frequency",
                     xlab = "",
                     main = "") {
  cols = hcl(h = seq(0, 360, by = 120))
  
  h = hist(x,
           breaks = 24,
           plot = F)
  
  tb = table(y, cut(x, h$breaks))
  
  
  ylim <- c(-.05 * max(colSums(tb)),
            1.25 * max(colSums(tb)))
  
  barplot(
    tb,
    col = cols,
    ylim = ylim,
    ylab = ylab,
    xlab = xlab,
    main = main,
    axisnames = FALSE,
    border = NA,
    space = 0
  )
  
  barplot(
    colSums(tb),
    ylim = ylim,
    col = NA,
    ylab = ylab,
    xlab = xlab,
    main = main,
    axisnames = FALSE,
    add = T,
    space = 0
  )
  
  box()
  axis(1, seq(0,
              length(h$breaks) - 1,
              by = 5),
              seq(min(x),max(x), by = .5))
  axis(2)
  
  legend("topright", c(rownames(tb)), fill = cols,border = NA,)
}

with(
  iris,
  strathist(Sepal.Width, Species, xlab = "Sepal.Width", main = "Stratified Histogram")
)
```

[image]

Or you could go the somewhat easier route to use `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris,aes(x = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 25,aes(fill = Species)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 25, fill = NA, color = 'black') +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-09-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Yes, but the only way I can think of is to then add the colors using `polygon` which can be a bit annoying.

Comment: Yes it can since it's just a wrapper for polygon, but you still need to sort the coordinates out which is certainly possible but a bit of a hustle.